# how to get javascript to open php file?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

The `Photo.php` file is expected to show a message.

But when I add `?page=2` to address it doesn't call Photos function to open the `Photo.php` file.

```
function Photos() {
            var opt = <?php echo $_GET['page'];?>
            alert(opt);
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","Photo.php?page="+opt,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
            function showCat(option){
                 ....
           }


<?php 
                   if(isset($_GET['page'])){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
            ,'myPhotos();'
            , '</script>';
        }
                echo 'Results go here'; 
                ?>
```

**photo.php**

```
if(isset($_GET["page"])){
    echo "photo";
}
```

Comment: var opt = '<?php echo $_GET['page'];?>';

Comment: Maybe this is just a typo, and it depends on the server, but aside from what Akam wrote, the problem could be that you're calling Photo.php while the file is actually called photo.php (lowercase). Again, might just be a typo.

Comment: **Don't** echo user input directly out to the page. It makes you **vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks**!

Comment: If you have PHP generating JavaScript/HTML and "it doesn't work". Then look at the source in your browser. Determine if the problem is that the client side code doesn't do what you expect (in which case, don't show us the PHP code) or if the PHP doesn't generate the client side code you expect.

Comment: Does the request fail or is it just blank? This is relevant to TJ's answer.

Comment: @m.brindley, does not show anything

Comment: @Quentin, whats your suggestion ?

Comment: @SaeedPirdost This probably implies that TJ's answer is correct or you are directing the request to the wrong spot (although it seems alright).

Comment: @SaeedPirdost — Read up on XSS and how to defend yourself from it.

Comment: @SaeedPirdost What Quentin is trying to tell you is that you should see if the problem is with PHP or JavaScript. Best way to check it out is use Firefox with firebug plugin installed. Load the page, hit F12, reload the page and see if there are any errors/failed xmlhttprequests or JavaScript errors (check console tab for that).

Comment: @HMR, I added the alert it seems it does not get to the function at all, as the alert does not show up.

Comment: Then try installing firebug and see what you get in the console. It probably is a syntax error. Your post still shows var opt = <?php echo $_GET['page'];?> instead of var opt = '<?php echo $_GET['page'];?>'

Comment: @HMR, Thats the answer please write it in answers for me to accept it as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Akam noticed; you forgot to put quotes around the string variable:

```
var opt = <?php echo $_GET['page'];?>
```

Should be:

```
var opt = '<?php echo $_GET['page'];?>';
```

This should have cased a JavaScript error that could have been noticed in the console of Firebug. Firebug is a very handy plugin to work out JavaScript or network problems. In the console you can find xmlhttpreqest with request and response headers as well as JavaScript errors and if you need to see details of JavaScript objects you can console.log(myObject) to the console where it can be clicked on to show more details.

I'm not sure if chrome has the same features but if you don't have Firefox or just like Chrome better then pressing F12 will open developer tools, same as in Opera and Internet explorer although I personally prefer Firefox with firebug plugin.

Answer (score 6):

> `xmlhttp.open("GET","Photo.php?page"+opt,true);`

I think you're missing an `=` in there...

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","Photo.php?page="+opt,true);
// Here --------------------------^
```

At least, that's what it looks like. It looks like you're accepting a `GET` argument, and then calling `Photo.php` and passing in a query string where `page` is the name of the query parameter.

Side note: All URL parameters must be correctly encoded. So you should be using `encodeURIComponent` there as well:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","Photo.php?page="+encodeURIComponent(opt),true);
```

(Technically both the key and value have to be URI encoded, but the URI-encoded version of `"page"` is `"page"`, so...)

---

All modern browsers have fairly useful debugging tools now, by the way. For instance, in Chrome you can open the Developer Tools and look at the Network tab to see *exactly* what you're sending the server and what it's sending back. Very useful for this sort of thing.

Comment: @I did both still same problem

Comment: @SaeedPirdost: Well, you definitely do need the `=`, but apparently there's also something *else* wrong. Only thing for it is to debug it (see the note I added to the end of the answer a couple of minutes ago).

Comment: @SaeedPirdost: Again: *"...apparently there's **also** something **else** wrong..."* and *"Only thing for it is to debug it..."*